Managed Migration Service of Azure Postgres Sibgle Server to Flexible server
I have been trying to migrate a database hosted in Azure PostgreSQL single server to Flexible server using the managed migration service provided. The migration fails with Foreign Key Constraint Failure Error. On further analysis I found that, on a particular table having a NULL-able column with unique constraint, the rows having NULL values in that column are not migrated. This led to subsequent failures.
Has any one faced this issue? If so how has been resolved?
Additional Info:
Azure internally uses pgcopydb utility
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/migrate/migration-service/concepts-migration-service-postgresql#additional-information
https://github.com/dimitri/pgcopydb/issues/756

check if this article https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-data-migration-blog/migrate-your-database-from-postgresql-single-server-to/ba-p/2093660 helps you.

I have seen this article, but it was a bit confusing. It says,
"-- Disable triggers at target Azure Database for PostgreSQL
The migration service internally handles the enable/disable of foreign keys and triggers to ensure a reliable and robust data migration. As a result, you do not have to worry about making any modifications to the target database schema.
So you don't need to manually disable it."
But then again executes commands to manipulate the constraints on the target DB

Also the article talk about DMS (classic). I am using the Migration Service in Azure Database for PostgreSQL (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-postgresql/harness-the-power-of-the-migration-service-in-azure-database-for/ba-p/4039471)
